# Temperature circuit not functioning

Tags: thermocouple, max31856

I am attempting to help mentor some high school kids on circuits and obviously not doing a very good job.  We are trying to get a prototype PCB working that uses a max31856mud [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/MAX31856-555593.pdf) and k thermocouple to measure temperature everything appears to be set up great, but the microcontroller OLED is just reading 32F at all times.

This same setup was used on a breakout board using the same temperature IC and worked fine see the pictures below.  The only change seems to be the ground pin selected.  Does anyone see any potential problems?

I noticed this microcontroller has 5 ground pins should I expect connecting 1 to be sufficient?

[image: schematic]

[image: board]

[image: breakout]

[image: pre soldering]

Comment: possibly a bad connection somewhere ... that may cause the zero reading

Comment: You are doing a great job for trying! Very few high school kids get exposed to cool stuff like this at their age. Check all DC levels by measuring voltage as close to the component pins as possible. Measure conductivity of traces from one end to the other (beep-function in a multimeter). Measure the circuit for shorts (how many ohms from MISO to GND etc). If you have an oscilloscope put it on SPI clock and see what's there, then MISO, MOSI.

Comment: The IC is not the easiest one to solder, if it has problems you can try to remove some solder with a solder wick / copper braid.

Comment: I have not used this chip, but 32.0 can't be random. My guess is that something is stuck at 0 (celsius), that is being converted to Fahrenheit resulting in 32.0. Sorry for not being more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The value of 32°F is 0°C, reading always zero likely means there is a problem with communication. Are you sure you have the SPI lines connected and set in software correctly?

On the breadboard, the break-out board has a different order of pins than the chip itself (CS is to the left of SDI, while on the schematic it is above SCK).

Comment: it looks like the ground pin was different as well